# For Loop in VBA Excel Macro condition not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run the below VBA code and it is running. However the results are not as expected in some cases
For example 
I have a column of values, the script looks at the whole column chooses the smallest value and add +1 to the output.
However sometimes it is skipping some small values in this original column and taking higher values and I cannot understand why it is doing that

I have attached the excel macro workbook here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IAHalTjWoTqRT10mgF6bu5l4VB1HgCfv

The output sheet is called: "Loop" 
The macro can be run from sheet: "Instruction"

```
Option Explicit


Sub Loop_Forecast()


Dim Onglet_Loop As String
Dim First_Ligne, First_Col_Fct, Col_SKU, Col_Inventory, Col_Monthly_Demand, Col_Coverage As Integer
Dim i, Last_ligne, Ligne_Smallest As Long
Dim Qty_Fct_Origin, Qty_Fct_Remain, Compteur, Smallest_Coverage As Variant


'Fige l'écran pendant la suppression des lignes
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Onglet_Loop = "Loop"
Worksheets(Onglet_Loop).Activate

First_Ligne = 3
Last_ligne = Cells(First_Ligne, 1).End(xlDown).Row

Qty_Fct_Origin = Cells(1, 2).Value
Col_SKU = 1
Col_Inventory = 2
Col_Monthly_Demand = 3
Col_Coverage = 4
First_Col_Fct = 5

Compteur = 0

Do While Compteur < Qty_Fct_Origin

        Compteur = Compteur + 1
        Smallest_Coverage = Cells(First_Ligne, Col_Coverage).Value
        Ligne_Smallest = First_Ligne

    For i = First_Ligne + 1 To Last_ligne
        If Cells(i, Col_Coverage).Value < Smallest_Coverage Then
            Smallest_Coverage = Cells(i, Col_Coverage).Value
            Ligne_Smallest = i
        End If
    Next i

        Cells(Ligne_Smallest, First_Col_Fct).Value = Cells(Ligne_Smallest, First_Col_Fct).Value + 1
Loop


'Faire plein de choses qui affectent le contenu des cellules
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

I have attached an image of the output I am receiving. As can be seen it is skipping some smaller values i.e 4 which should be priority and then jumping to 5
[image]

Comment: Quick note: Your variables aren't which I assume you believe them to be. `Onglet_Loop` is a string as you probably expect, however only `Col_Coverage` is an Integer and only `Ligne_Smallest` is a Long; every other variable is a Variant.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you trying to achieve in this process but pay attention that column D has formulas that depend on values in column E where you store the values from the procedure

Comment: This code makes a loop for 10.000 times. Each loop check all numbers in column D, locates the minimum one, and then in same row but column E, it increases the value by 1. So after macro is done, the value shown in column E is the number of times that value of D has been the minimun one. Actually, if you sum up all values in column E, you'll get 10.000 (your loop). So after executing code, I do not understand your question or problem. The code works good. Why do you say it does not? please, be more specific

Comment: Also, please note your cells are formated to show no decimals, but when executing code, **all decimals are being included**. You are not comparing integers in VBA. If you want to compare integers, change the formula in Excel. Instead of `=(B3+SUM(E3:E3))/C3` use something like `=ROUND((B3+SUM(E3:E3))/C3;0)`. When formatting a cell in Excel, **it does not affect the real value stored in cell**. It is just a visual modificaction, but if the value got decimals, it will be stored as decimal, not integer, even if you see it as an integer.